# How to use in operator on text[] column data type?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use `IN` operator in a `text[]` column. But I got this error message:

`ERROR: operator does not exist: text = text[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts`.

Is it possible to use IN operator in this context? If not what should I use?

I've tried casting into json/jsonb, use `ANY`, or @> operator without success

Reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE visitor (name varchar(255), hobbies text[]);
CREATE TABLE hobbies(name varchar(255), id text);

INSERT INTO visitor (name, hobbies) VALUES ('sanghin', '{ida}');
INSERT INTO hobbies (name, id) VALUES ('sql', 'ida');

SELECT name FROM hobbies WHERE id IN (SELECT hobbies FROM visitor WHERE visitor.name = 'sanghin');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22bb18f6726282d38f524d1e16bcb0ff)

```
SELECT name 
FROM hobbies 
WHERE id IN 
     (SELECT unnest(hobbies) FROM visitor WHERE visitor.name = 'sanghin');
```

Your subquery returns a set of arrays. Then you are trying to compare a text with elements of the set. So your are trying to compare type `text` with type `text[]` which wouldn't work. Unnesting the array gives you a set of text values. The comparison works.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an EXISTS predicate:

```sql
select h.name 
from hobbies h
where exists (select *
              from visitor v
              where v.name = 'sanghin'
                and h.id = any(v.hobbies));
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=31dccde104dd830c43c211fcd458e8ed)